# Validate existing entity in CQRS + EventSourcing. Microservice ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am currently building an app, and I would like to use micro services.
I use Mediatr for implementing a CQRS pattern and EventStore for event sourcing.

I have a problem with checking that an entity exists before creating an event of aggregate and appending it to the EventStore.

For example: I have LanguageAggregateRoot

```
public class LanguageAggregateRoot 
{
    public Guid Id {get;set}
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public bool Enable { get; private set; }
    public string Icon { get; private set; }
}
```

Field `Code` is unique and user can change code for language.

When I use `Code` field for stream id of eventstore, if the user sends a `CreateLanguageCommand` and `ChangeCodeCommand`, I need to check that the new code exists.

So I use Id field for stream id. But I don't understand how I can validate whether code field is unique?

As far as I've found out should not use query handling in command handling.

If i use client to check existed then send command to server. I think it doesn't look good. Because something/someone can request only command with out my client.

How can I do that?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Do it in your rest api layer -- the controllers. They are the real client of your business logic, not the end-user's browser -- that's a client of the API. That layer should have access to both the query and command side and can validate user input before creating the command.

Comment: So, Api layer -- RestApi or OData Controller, GrpcService -- GrpcBase or GraphQL layer is a client of business logic. That right? Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine to validate your request in your command itself.
you can use the below link for more details.
[CQRS - is it allowed to call the read side from the write side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338117/cqrs-is-it-allowed-to-call-the-read-side-from-the-write-side)

Comment: So, Api layer -- RestApi or OData Controller, GrpcService -- GrpcBase or GraphQL layer is a client of business logic. That right? Thanks you.

Comment: @MinhMít I would avoid placing the logic for handling commands to the API layer. You already mentioned three options, would you be happy to copy-paste your logic to another API if you decide to change or add a transport? That's what a command service does, and the API layer is just a mean to call it.